# gnuplot matrix or plot : display both color and point value

Tags: matrix, colors, numbers, gnuplot, point

I'm using gnuplot to analysis data.

And I frequently use palette and matrix.

However whenever I use that, precision is always problem.

If I increase precision by define many color, it is difficult to remember and to read.

If I decrease number of color to clear comparison, precision become decrease.

So I'm thinking matrix with plot number.
[image: example of matrix]

If I can display both color and number, it will be more easy to see and analysis.

At least I want display only number,(Just use excel is a one choice but I don't want to)

or display number with different color.(color determined by point value)

If you know the way to do, please let me know.

If you can't understand, please tell me.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To plot the labels, just use the `with labels` plotting style. You can use any string and string formatting e.g. with `sprintf` to set the label:

```
reset
set autoscale fix
set palette defined (0 'white', 1 'green')
set tics scale 0
unset cbtics
set cblabel 'Score'
unset key
plot 'data.txt' matrix with image,\
     '' matrix using 1:2:(sprintf('%.2f', $3)) with labels font ',16'
```

The result with the `pngcairo` terminal and gnuplot 4.6.3 is:

[image]

The data file `data.txt` for this example is:

```
0.22 0.13 0.54 0.83 0.08
0.98 0.57 0.52 0.24 0.66
0.23 0.68 0.24 0.89 0.76
0.89 0.78 0.69 0.78 0.10
0.24 0.77 0.27 0.28 0.69
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

To expand the above answer: One often finds the case, that the labels should have different colors in order to be readable. To produce white labels on a dark background and black labels on bright background I use the following code:

```
threshold = 123456
f = "..."
plot f matrix with image ,\
     '' matrix using 1:2:($3 > threshold ? sprintf('%1.2f', $3) : sprintf("")) with labels tc "white" ,\
     '' matrix using 1:2:($3 < threshold ? sprintf('%1.2f', $3) : sprintf("")) with labels tc "black"
```

Comment: good idea! It can also be done in a single line: `'' matrix using 1:2:(sprintf('%.2f',$3)):($3<threshold ? 0 : 0x00ffffff) w labels tc rgb var`